# How to embed an avi video inside Powerpoint ppt file using Apache POI HSLF?

Tags: java, powerpoint, apache-poi

Tried this:

```
int idx4 = ppt.addMovie(new File("Animation.avi").getCanonicalPath(), MovieShape.MOVIE_AVI);
MovieShape pict4 = new MovieShape(idx4, idx4);

pict4.setAnchor(new java.awt.Rectangle(100, 100, 300, 200));

Slide slide4 = ppt.createSlide();
slide4.addShape(pict4);
```

without success. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Apache POI MovieShape Test](http://massapi.com/source/poi-3.7/src/scratchpad/testcases/org/apache/poi/hslf/model/TestMovieShape.java.html) class helped me out.